# i am unable to access radgrid column in javascript....how i can access this..?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am using radgrid  in asp.net and i want to access label of radgrid named "editor_status" in javascript...it is not accessible in javascipt...on the hand if i take simple label outside the grid then it is accessible in javascript...i tried the following code:

html:

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn  DataField="Editor_status" HeaderText="Editor_status" ReadOnly="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Editor_status"     runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Editor_status")%>' BackColor="SkyBlue"  Font-Size="14px"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>




    <script>

     $(document).ready(function () {
     var a=document.getElementById('<%=editor_status.ClientID%>').innerText;
    });

    </script>
```

it can not be access the lablel...
on the other hand if i take just label like outside the radgrid

```
<label id="editor_status1"    runat="server" >Available</label>
```

then it is accessible in javascript....how i can access label inside the radgrid..

Comment: I would guess that, since it's in a grid, there is potentially more than one copy of the label created? Maybe one in each row of the grid? Therefore it makes no logical sense to try and get by the ID....which copy of the label are you trying to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using grid so you can't access label inside the grid directly but you can create a javascript function to access each of the lable inside the radgrid.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $.each($find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_dataItems(), function (index, value) {
            if (value.findElement("Editor_status") == null) 
            {
                var a = value.findElement("Editor_status").innerText;
            }
        });
});
```

Try this it should work.

Comment: if you are using MasterTableView then you need change logic somewhat in $.each method like $.each($find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().get_dataItems(), function (index, value)